# How do I get Selenium Button Click to work?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I'm a complete beginner, I have a website in which I want to click a button through python selenium, I've tried a lot of things, but I can't get it to work.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


chromedriver_location = executable_path=r"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_location)
driver.get('https://maskun.org/donate/')

donate_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'give-btn advance-btn')] and text()='Donate Now']")))
donate_button.click()
```

Right now, I'm getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\pythonprojects\maskun.py", line 13, in <module>
    donate_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'give-btn advance-btn')] and text()='Donate Now']")))
  File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 81, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
  File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 312, in _predicate
    target = driver.find_element(*target)  # grab element at locator
  File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 856, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 429, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //button[contains(@class, 'give-btn advance-btn')] and text()='Donate Now'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//button[contains(@class, 'give-btn advance-btn')] and text()='Donate Now']' is not a valid XPath expression.      
  (Session info: chrome=106.0.5249.119)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x00B51ED3+2236115]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AE92F1+1807089]
        Ordinal0 [0x009F66FD+812797]
        Ordinal0 [0x009F92B4+823988]
        Ordinal0 [0x009F9165+823653]
        Ordinal0 [0x009F9400+824320]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A25352+1004370]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A257CB+1005515]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A57632+1209906]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A41AD4+1120980]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A559E2+1202658]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A418A6+1120422]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A1A73D+960317]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A1B71F+964383]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00DFE7E2+2743074]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00DF08D4+2685972]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00BE2BAA+532202]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00BE1990+527568]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AF080C+1837068]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AF4CD8+1854680]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AF4DC5+1854917]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AFED64+1895780]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76046739+25]
        RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77858FD2+1218]
        RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77858F9D+1165]
```

If I inspect the button on chrome I get:

```
<button class="give-btn advance-btn" tabindex="1">Donate Now<i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
```

The XPath is:

```
//*[@id="give-form-746-1"]/div[1]/button
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to switch to frame first than find_elemnt

```
driver.get('https://maskun.org/donate/')
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[@name='give-embed-form']")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
donate_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Donate Now')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error inside the XPath expression.
Also, you need to scroll the page down and switch to the `iframe` block since that button is inside an `iframe`.
The following code works

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
url = 'https://maskun.org/donate/'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, arguments[0]);", 600)
time.sleep(1)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[name='give-embed-form']")))

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'give-btn advance-btn') and text()='Donate Now']"))).click()
```

Don't forget to switch from the `iframe` when you finished working inside it with

```py
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: This is the error I get now: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\pythonprojects\maskun.py", line 14, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'give-btn advance-btn') and text()='Donate Now']"))).click()
  File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 90, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`